# If $P(A)=0$ then every root of $P(x)$ is a possible eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P(x)$ a polynomial, and matrix $A$ of order $n \times n$.

If $P(A)=0$ then **every** root of $P(x)$ is a **possible** eigenvalue of $A$.

Is that true? and why?

EDIT: Example for use:

Let $A$ of order $4 \times 4$. And $A$ satisfies $A^2+2A+I=0$. Find eigenvalues of $A$.

I'm saying that the root of this polinomial is $-1$ so this have to be the only eigenvalue of $A$ so the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(x+1)^4$.

Comment: I think it wrong. For example, $P(x) = (x-1)^2(x+1)$. We have $P(I_2) = 0$ but $-1$ is not eigenvalue of $I_2$.

Comment: What is a *possible eigenvalue*?

Comment: This seems like it might be related to the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

Comment: @GAVD You may turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Since an $n×n$ matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, and we obtain the eigenvalues of $A$ as the roots of its characteristic polynomial, then it would make sense that the roots of $P(x)$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. But there is also the possibility that $A$ just satisfies $P(A)=0$ even though $P(X)$ is not its characteristic polynomial, so I would say in general it is not always true.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well, I edited with example.

Comment: The logic you want is "every eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of $P$".

Comment: @Hurkyl Is that a theorm? How do I prove that?

Comment: Multiply by an eigenvector.